# Where does php+laravel reads db connection string because runtime defaulting to user id not defined anywhere in my app?

Tags: php, laravel, azure

I am hosting my php+laravel rest API application in azure app service (windows). The app server comes with 'mysql in app' (build into it). I am able access the mysql database through myphpadmin. I can see there were two predefined users, one is ***root*** and another one is ***azure***. To connect to database using myphpadmin, it uses azure user id.

In my application in **.env** I have **DB_USERNAME** set to **azure** and in database.php, if the user id is not found in config default it is set to default to 'azure'. Also in azure app server's app setting I have all the connection strings defined and there as well, I am using azure as the DB_USERNAME.

But when I ran postman to one of the end point, I noticed, the end point is failing because of  "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'". I am really confused where would my application uses root as the username instead of azure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to run `php artisan config:cache` command when you change any data in env

laravel always read config data from its cache.

so if your `.env` credentials are changed in server you also have to cache again that credentials

also make sure that your database config file reading all the credentials from `.env` by default.

Example:

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST','localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE','billing'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME','root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '1234'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        )
```

Note:

> If you execute the config:cache command during your deployment
>   process, you should be sure that you are only calling the env function
>   from within your configuration files. Once the configuration has been
>   cached, the .env file will not be loaded and all calls to the env
>   function will return null.

Answer (score -1):

You also need to configure it not just in `.env` as @EmtiazZahid has suggested to you, and you must restart your server each time you do any configuration in `.env`

Comment: as long as 'php artisan config:clear' called, no. you don't need to restart the server

Comment: @punk73 you are new to laravel I think, before you must need to restart the server for any change in .env but in latest versions you don't need to restart. It's been two years now for laravel versions.